# Tuning Ruby / Rails to work on systems with less memory

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memory, garbage-collection

I'm trying to run an RoR app on an Amazon micro instance (the one which comes in the free tier). However, I'm being unable to successfully complete `rake assets:precompile` because it supposedly runs out of RAM and the system kills the process.

First, how can I be sure that this is a low memory issue?

Second, irrespective of the answer to the first question, are there some parameters that I can pass to the Ruby interpreter to make it consume less RAM -- even if at the cost of overall app performance? Any GC tuning possible? Anything at all?

Note: Similar to [Making ruby on rails take up less memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249504/making-ruby-on-rails-take-up-less-memory)

PS: I've added a a file-based swap area to the system as well. Here's the output of `cat /proc/meminfo` if that helps:

```
MemTotal:         604072 kB
MemFree:          343624 kB
Buffers:            4476 kB
Cached:            31568 kB
SwapCached:        33052 kB
Active:            17540 kB
Inactive:         199588 kB
Active(anon):      11408 kB
Inactive(anon):   172644 kB
Active(file):       6132 kB
Inactive(file):    26944 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:        292840 kB
SwapFree:         165652 kB
Dirty:                80 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        149640 kB
Mapped:             6620 kB
Shmem:              2964 kB
Slab:              23744 kB
SReclaimable:      14044 kB
SUnreclaim:         9700 kB
KernelStack:        2056 kB
PageTables:         6776 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      594876 kB
Committed_AS:     883644 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:        5200 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359732767 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      637952 kB
DirectMap2M:           0 kB
```

Comment: Okay, so I've lost 50points on my rep and still been unable to get a satisfactory solution for this :(

Answer (score 1):

Put `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in application.rb to avoid initializing the app and the database connection when you precompile assets. That may help.

Another option is to precompile locally and then deploy the compiled assets. More info here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Answer (score 0):

Second question first - I have run Rails apps on Micro instances, and do so now. So long as your concurrency is very low (one or two active users, tops. And not super-active either) you will be ok. Also note that Amazon will arbitrarily throttle down your effective CPU whenever it wants if you try to slam the CPU too hard (that's just how they do Micro instances). No GC tweaks or anything like that are necessary, just default settings are fine. I was using Passenger, an older version, and made sure it was spinning up only one process spawner. Stock config. Especially if big chunks of your app are images or static files, your main web server will be serving most of that content, and not Rails.

For your second question - I just checked out a large(ish) rails app, fat_free_crm, on a freshly spun-up micro instance. I was just looking for something big.

I timed a run of assets:precompile and it did complete - after a very long time. I timed it and it seemed to finish in 2 minutes 31 seconds.

I think you might still need more swapspace. I would try a gig to start with. If you *still* can't precompile your assets after that, you've got some other problem.

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1k count=1M`

`mkswap /swapfile`

`swapon -f /swapfile`